# Insert an array into 2 seperate MySQL tables - PHP

Tags: php

I need assistance in inserting an array into multiple tables.

My array looks as follows:

```
Array ( 
[customerId] => 4 
[DateCreated] => 2015-04-28 
[Description] => This is a test invoice 
[Amount] => 19.79
[invoiceline] => Array ( 
                   [0] => Array ( [description] => Product A [amount] => 5.00 ) 
                   [1] => Array ( [description] => Product B [amount] => 6.99 ) 
                   [2] => Array ( [description] => Product C [amount] => 7.80 ) 
                  ) 
)
```

My 2 tables are:

**INVOICES**
Id
CustomerId
Description
DateCreated
Amount

**INVOICELINES**
Id
InvoiceId - (would 1st need to insert into invoices in order to obtain last record inserted)
Description
DateCreated
Amount

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please re-post question more clear..

Comment: So are you inserting the array into 2 separate tables ?

Comment: Yes, I was wanting to insert the array into 2 separate tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Use PHP PDO Where Possible

The use of the 'mysql' API has been discouraged for years now. Whilst the 'mysqli' API  is great for those transitioning over, if you are willing to learn a new (and I believe better) way of doing things the 'PDO' API is really the way to go.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Using 'PDO' Prepared Statements eliminates the possibility of SQL injection attacks ***and*** provides the ability to only 'prepare' the query once.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Using transactions eliminates the possibility of orphaned records. IE: Should an error occur whilst inserting data into more than one table at a time.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Lastly, using (exception) try / catch blocks allows to handle database connection errors gracefully.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

### The Code

```
<?php

// Your array.
$array = array('customerId' => 4,
               'DateCreated' => '2015-04-28',
               'Description' => 'This is a test invoice',
               'Amount' => 19.79,
               'invoiceline' => array(array('description' => 'Product A',
                                            'amount' => 5.00),
                                      array('description' => 'Product B',
                                            'amount' => 6.99),
                                      array('description' => 'Product C',
                                            'amount'=> 7.80)
                                     ) 
              );

// Set your database connection details.
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'your_db_name';
$db_username = 'your_db_username';
$db_password = 'your_db_password';

// Create the database connection handle (using mysql).
try {
    $dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // If it failed let the user know.
}

// Insert the data.
try {
    // Begin the transaction.
    $dbh->beginTransaction();

    // Insert data into the 'INVOICES' table.
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO INVOICES (CustomerId, DateCreated, Description, Amount)  
                           VALUES (:customerId, :DateCreated, :Description, :Amount)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':customerId', $array['customerId'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':DateCreated', $array['DateCreated'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Description', $array['Description'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Amount', $array['Amount'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the last inserted id.
    $last_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    // Insert data into the 'INVOICELINES' table.
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO INVOICELINES (InvoiceId, Description, DateCreated, Amount)  
                           VALUES (:InvoiceId, :Description, :DateCreated, :Amount)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':InvoiceId', $last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':Description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':DateCreated', $array['DateCreated'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
    $stmt->bindParam(':Amount', $amount, PDO::PARAM_INT);  

    foreach ($array['invoiceline'] as $key => $value) {
        $description = $value['description'];
        $amount = $value['amount'];
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    // Commit the transaction.
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // If it failed, rollback the transaction and let the user know.
    $dbh->rollBack();
}
```

I hope this helps.

PS: Remember, don't stop learning...

Answer (score 0):

You need to split array before second insert:

Do like this:

```
$dataArr = array("customerId" => 4,
    "DateCreated" => "2015-04-28",
    "Description" => "This is a test invoice",
    "Amount" => 19.79,
    "invoiceline" => array(
        array("description" => "Product A", "amount" => 5.00),
        array("description" => "Product B", "amount" => 6.99),
        array("description" => "Product C", "amount" => 7.80)
    )
);

$new_arr = $dataArr['invoiceline'];

$query1 = "INSERT INTO INVOICES (CustomerId, Description, DateCreated, Amount) VALUES ('".$dataArr['customerId']."', '".$dataArr['DateCreated']."', '".$dataArr['Description']."', '".$dataArr['Amount']."')" ;
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);

$last_insertid = mysql_insert_id();

foreach($new_arr as $narr){

$query1 = "INSERT INTO INVOICELINES  (InvoiceId, Description, Amount) VALUES ('".$last_insertid."', '".$narr['Description']."', '".$narr['Amount']."')" ;
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
}
```

Let me know for more help!

Comment: Worked well. Made some tweaks to fit my file structure. Thank you